# Как провести график прямой через выбранную точку, на уже существующем графике с помощью C3.js

Tags: javascript, график, d3.js

Допустим есть функция `y=x*x`. Я построила её график с помощью C3.js Теперь я хочу на этом же графике выбрать в браузере рандомную точку (пусть к примеру (1,1)) и построить через неё график. Как это реализовать?

Знаю, как просто вывести значения в график:

```
    <div id="chart"></div>
<script>

    var functionDataY = ['yLabel']
    var functionDataX = ['xLabel']

    for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    functionDataY.push(i*i);
    functionDataX.push(i);
        }

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
    xs: {
    'yLabel': 'xLabel',
    },
columns: [
    functionDataY,
    functionDataX
        ]
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: @Kromster, имею ввиду именно c3.js (c3 построена на базе d3)

Comment: @Kromster, спасибо за правки в вопросе)

Comment: Не за что. Вы тоже можете поправить вопрос. Например, не совсем понятен момент "Я **построила** её график .. Теперь я хочу на этом же графике **выбрать** в браузере рандомную **точку** (пусть к примеру (1,1)) и **построить** через неё **график**"